# Run threads with boost and asio

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-asio

**Introduction**

I'm trying create a thread to receive data from socket.

**Code**

```
void ClientTcp::read_handler(tcp::socket s){
    for(;;){
        char buffer[max_buffr];
        boost::system::error_code error;
        size_t length = s.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer), error);
        if (error == boost::asio::error::eof)
            break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
        else if (error)
            throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
        buffer[length] = '\0';
        std::cout << "-> " << buffer << std::endl;
    }
}

void ClientTcp::run(){
    tcp::socket s(io_service_);
    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
    boost::asio::connect(s, resolver.resolve({ip_, port_}));

    boost::thread read_th(read_handler, std::move(s));
    std::string message;
    for(;;){
        std::cin >> message;
        boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(message, message.size()));
    }
    read_th.join();
}
```

**Problem**

This line `boost::thread read_th(read_handler, std::move(s));` has a bug that i can't understand.

**Error** 
`no matching function for call to boost::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type, 
std::remove_reference<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&>::type)`

**Main Question** 
How I launch a thread from class method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer the wrong question: You'd use `boost::bind`

```
boost::thread read_th(boost::bind(&ClientTcp::read_handler, this, std::move(s)));
```

But you *certainly* do not want to do that. Use a thread per asynchronous operation doesn't work at all.

Boost let's you achieve asynchrony without the need for additional threads. Just use the `async_*` functions instead of the functions you
re using:

- `async_read_some`
- `async_write`.

Don't forget to run `io_service::run()`.

Comment: Don't work, `error: use of deleted function ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket(const boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>&)’|`
I will try async methods.

Comment: Well . That just means `s` is not movable either. Use `boost::ref`, a pointer, a member etc. :)

Comment: Works ! Thanks, just update your answer with `boost::ref` example too.

Comment: Don't forget about the _"But you certainly do not want to do that"_ part. In your sample you have [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because the [socket is not thread safe](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html#boost_asio.reference.basic_socket.thread_safety)

Comment: @sehe `socket` *is* movable, but `bind` copies its arguments, so `std::move(s)` is quite pointless. The original version was more promising, perhaps `read_handler(tcp::socket &&s)` would do the job (actually, one must check when and how `boost::thread` forwards its arguments).

Comment: @IgorR. I'm without a computer here, but I'm pretty darn sure `boost::bind` copies the arguments _only in the sense_ that "copying an rvalue" implies a move. So, that's not pointless. The bound value will be passed to the completion handler as an lvalue reference, which could perfectly be moved from (remember, all rvalue-reference parameters are lvalues, which is why we need  `std::move` to cast). The thing to keep in mind is that the completion handler must not be invoked more than once to prevent multiple moves from the same bound object. (But all that minor w.r.t. to the OP's bigger issues)

Comment: @sehe Certainly, an object can be moved into the binder. By saying "pointless" I meant "w.r.t the target function", because, as you mentioned, the binder itself passes the arguments to the destination function as lvalues. They *could* be moved from (b.t.w asio guarantees the handler gets called no more than once), but the binder wouldn't `move` them (could it ever "memoize" which args were passed as rvalues?).

Comment: The point is the binder doesn't _need to_ move them in order for it to be "not pointless". I know Asio doesn't invoke the handler twice. Otherwise, I wouldn't have suggested the incantation. Regardless, all this is confusion in the margin of the OP's real problems :S

Comment: @sehe hmm... putting aside OP's real problems :) , I'm afraid I don't understand how the initial move would help, if the binder doesn't `move` further. (B.t.w std::thread does help, see my answer)

Comment: @IgorR. you'd simply take `tcp::socket&` in the read handler and move from it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `boost::thread` constructor is unable to perform "perfect forwarding" of its arguments (and you can't use `bind` for the reason described in the comments to @sehe answer).

However, being a part of C++11, `std::thread` does forward the arguments correctly, so the following compiles:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <thread>

using namespace boost::asio;

void read_handler(ip::tcp::socket && s)
{
} 

int main()
{
    io_service io;
    ip::tcp::socket s(io);
    std::thread read_th(read_handler, std::move(s));
}
```

Note that if `read_handler` is a non-static member function (like in your question), you should bind it with the object instance: `std::thread(&ClientTcp::read_handler, this, std::move(s));`

(Of course, the object lifespan should be taken into account, as well as the design considerations raised by @sehe.)